# Benefits of using Insert flag in Grails save()

Tags: grails, save, grails-domain-class

What are the benefits of using the grails insert flag when saving a domain class?

Here is an example:
Lets say I have a Domain Object FooBar:

```
FooBar foo = FooBar.find("foo")?: new FooBar(id:"foo")

foo.bar = "bar"

foo.save()
```

Would it be better do do something more like this:

```
boolean insertFlag
FooBar foo = FooBar.find("foo")

if(foo == null){
   insertFlag = false
}else {
   foo = new FooBar(id:"foo")
   insertFlag = true
}

foo.bar = "bar"

foo.save(insert: insertFlag)
```

I was thinking that the save would run smoother somehow with the insert flag verses not having it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`insert` inside `save` is highly useful if you have the id `generator` for a domain class as `assigned`. In that case the `id` has to be assigned by the user.

This is a way to inform hibernate that whether you want to `insert` a record or just want to `update`.

```
class FoofBar{
    String bar
    static mapping = {
        id generator: 'assigned'
    }
}

def fooBar = new FooBar(bar: 'foo')
fooBar.id = 100
fooBar.save() //inserts a record with id = 100

def secondFooBar = FooBar.get(100)
secondFooBar.id = 200
//want to insert as a new row instead of updating the old one.
//This forces hibernate to use the new assigned id
fooBar.save(insert: true)
```

[This](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/save.html) will make it clear.